# Add javascript in master page sharepoint 2013 using wsp solution file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, master-page

I added user control and then empty module to reference user control inside SharePoint 2013 master page but it is not working.

Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="150"  ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/UsageReport/SiteUsageActions.ascx">

I want a add  javascript in the Masterpage and deploy it as a feature. How to achieve this?

Comment: I want a add a javascript in masterpage using a solution and feature, how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include javascript in masterpage, using the code given below:

```
<SharePoint:Scriptlink ID="Scriptlink120" runat="server" name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/JS Path" language="javascript" />.
```

Add this in your master page and then deploy the solution.
This shall include the JS file globally which will allow you to use it at all places.

Comment: Mancy, i understand by giving reference in master page i can do that but i don't want to edit my master page file.

Comment: If you do not want to edit your master page, then you would need to include the javascript using the <script> in each and every place that you are using the JS. This is not a good alternative, so I suggest that you should include it once in the master page.

Comment: Mancy, there is a method Using Delegate Control through Feature we can achieve this. And that's what i am trying to implement but no luck :(   link http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/tipsntricks/pages/referencing-js-files-using-custom-action.aspx)

Comment: Please post the error that you get. And try referring this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx

Comment: nothing happens, no error and i don't get my alert.

Comment: This means that the javascript it not getting included. Please check your code thoroughly. Try to include JS using <script> if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best options to inject JavaScript in a SPWeb when activating a feature are:

- Use the `SPWeb.CustomJavaScriptFileUrl` property (set it from a feature event receiver)
- Use a Custom Action (see for instance http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/tipsntricks/pages/referencing-js-files-using-custom-action.aspx)
- Deploy your own custom master page, with the JS code embedded into it, and set this master as the master to be used by the site from a feature ER.

Comment: i want to add JS Using Delegate Control through Feature.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding wrong control source path,

```
Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="150" ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/UsageReport/SiteUsageActions.ascx"
```

just added `/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/` solved my problem.

```
Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="150" ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/UsageReport/SiteUsageActions.ascx">
```